# Any tomcat version support <url-regexp> tag for URL mapping in web.xml

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets

Can anybody tell me that Is there any Tomcat version supports  tag for URL mapping in web.xml?  It is supported in Resin.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That is a container specific feature that is not supported in any Apache Tomcat version.